# Close Android keyboard on start

Tags: java, android

I have a variable from xml:

> editTextInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextInput);

When the application loads the keyboard is shown, but I want to hide it, and if the user want to have it back she has to click on the EditText-field to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 InputMethodManager inputManager = 
            (InputMethodManager) context.
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```